# Calling Objects and Passing Variables in Python Pygame Not Working Error Says Variable Not Defined

Tags: python, image, pygame, window

I'm a bit confused as to how objects and passing work in Python. I would like to make an object to call functions of a class, but I can't seem to get the mainWindow variable to pass. I keep getting an error saying mainWindow has not been defined

I made a program in TKinter years ago and had everything within a main method and after each function was finished it would call the next function and pass variables. I wanted to see if I could just do the same thing by calling functions through an object.

```
import pygame
pygame.init

class PreviewWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        mainWindow = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Sprite Viewer')

    def loadImage(self, mainWindow):
        userImage = pygame.image.load('well.png')
        imageSize = userImage.get_rect()

    def drawImage(self, userImage, imageSize):
        mainWindow.blit(userImage, imageSize)
        pygame.display.flip()

previewObj = PreviewWindow
previewObj.loadImage(mainWindow)
previewObj.drawImage(mainWindow, userImage, imageSize)
```

I want to understand how to call functions within classes while being able to pass variables and functions to said functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of things going on here. First of all, you are defining `mainWindow` within the `__init__` function's scope. This means it cannot be referenced from outside the function. You are using OOP correctly until you begin passing mainWindow into your class's methods. Instead, just use the `mainWindow` that is defined already by `__init__`!

You can do this by setting `self.mainWindow`. `self` makes the property object specific.

```py
import pygame
pygame.init

class PreviewWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        # initialize your mainWindow
        self.mainWindow = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Sprite Viewer')

    def loadImage(self, imageName):
        self.userImage = pygame.image.load(imageName)
        self.imageSize = userImage.get_rect()

    def drawImage(self):
        # use the mainWindow you initialized in __init__
        self.mainWindow.blit(self.userImage, self.imageSize)
        pygame.display.flip()

previewObj = PreviewWindow()
previewObj.loadImage('well.png')
previewObj.drawImage()
```

Comment: Cool, that fixed my mainWindow issue, but now I get an error saying userImage is not defined on line 21, the last line.

Comment: @w2019py I reworked your code given the way you appear to want it to work. Try again now. If it works, please accept my answer!